# Paint jComponent that is on a partially transparent JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, opacity, paintcomponent

I have a JLabel with a MouseListener to look like a link. Thus if you hover on it the color changes.

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
    setForeground(new Color(255,134,0));
}
```

This JLabel is on a JPanel that is only partially transparent

```
panel.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,100));
```

As I hover over the link it changes color like it should but the transparent background "glitches". It makes the background in the area of the text white and there is also some random letters on the white. This disappears as soon as I re-size the window so obviously then a certain paint is called that repaint that part correctly.

My problem is I have called every single paint method in that JFrame and also the JFrame's but the background still glitches. So is there another way to do this or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to change the background panel to "transparent" (`setOpaque(false)`), which is probably going to require to override the `paintComponent` method and fill it yourself with the background color.  This way, the repaint manager knows it needs to paint the components below it.

Comment: Failing to honor the [opacity](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#props) property can cause such rendering artifact; also, factor out constant colors.